# Keycloak redirect fails when number of roles are in the hundreds

Tags: keycloak

I have 2 users, one with less than 30 roles and one with 400 roles. When I login with the 30 role user, I can reach the redirect URL without issues. But when I log in with the 400 role user, the request to the redirect URL doesn't complete. If I reduce the number of roles in the 400 role user then it will work. So, is there a way to disable passing roles in the java access token or increase some limit somewhere that's causing the failure?

Comment: Hello, if I understand well your question.. "disable passing roles" seems quite counter-natural. Also I don't want to be spicy but if there is a limit somewhere I'd push for it to be even lower.. as having hundreds of roles also seem counter-natural and especially dangerous (without speaking about maintenance). By the way do you know `least-privilege` principle?

Comment: @bsaverino Yes, I agree that the usage is a little iffy. What we have are ~3000 resources (non-URL) that are identifiable with strings in the backend. Each user will have a list of accessible resources. So a role was created for each resource and assigned to users if they have access to that resource. This way, when the access token is passed to the back end, we can look up the roles and get a list of resources the user has access to. Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Hi, does any answer fits your needs? If so, do you mind accepting the "answer"? (cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). This will help us and future visitors.  If not, please let us know what's missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to focus rather on **roles reduction/optimization** than forcing the transmission (raising limits) over the maximum number of roles inside tokens (or anywhere else).

Some **interesting questions** (among others) to start with:

- Which protected resources am I going to serve?
- What am I trying to protect? and what are the associated risks? (build a **Threat Model**)
- How do resources are served by each application? and how are they distributed among my applications?
- What kind of resources are they? How can I group them? Which sets are identifiable? or what are the relationships between them? What actions are possible against all sets of resources?
- Who are the users of each application? How will they interact with my resources? Which flows are sensitive?
- What roles can I define for all my resources?
- Which role can apply to each application, resource type or set?
- What kind of user groups can I create?
- Do I need additional attributes or claims for each set of roles or users/groups?

I firmly believe that if you answer all these questions you will end up having a bunch of roles instead of hundreds. Think **security by design** and follow **principle of least privilege**.

---

### Focus on your use case

Now as far as I understand, your blocking point is that you are assuming that each resource is unique, sensitive and requires its own permissions, and consequently a role definition. While it may be true in some cases, in most other cases it does not mean that you have to use the token roles/scopes/claims to secure your assets deep at the resource-level. I'll try to illustrate this sentence by an example.

### RBAC and authorizations example for your use case

Let's assume that:

- you have millions of sensitive resources to serve
- each registered user of your application has access to a (different) set of these resources.
- your resources are splitted into, say, 3 categories (e-books, videos, musics).
- each resource can be downloaded, uploaded, deleted.
- your application will meet unregistered users, registered users, contributors and administrators
- registered users will always have read access to resources (not a single action will ever allow a modification)
- contributors are particular registered users who can perform special actions including modification ('upload', 'edit')
- contributors and administrators may have access to various administrative parts of the application
- your application will evolve by serving additional categories of resources in the future and new actions will be available to users later (such as 'flag', 'edit' or 'share link').

Then **first things first**:

- **organize your resources** accordingly by serving them behind categorized paths such as: `.../myapp/res/ebooks`,  `.../myapp/res/videos`, `.../myapp/res/musics`
- identify your resources via UUID such that a resource may look like: `.../myapp/res/ebooks/duz7327abdhgsd95a`

Now imagine that your business risks or at least the **greatest risks** you wish to avoid are:

- unregistered users having gaining access or rights for any part of the application or resource
- uncontrolled registration process (robots, spam, no mail verification, fake users, ...)
- registered users gaining illegal privileges (unauthorized actions, access to other categories, illegal administrative rights)
- discovery of available resources by any mean

You will note that I voluntarily didn't listed:

- registered user having illegal access to certain resources. For example: maliciously pointed/provided by an existing user.

This is because it is not a high risk as you may hold contact information about registered users as well as log activity and actions, quota or requests throttling, and you may be able to ban them or start legal action against them. Your registration process is also assumed robust and secure. Nonetheless if its considered a critical risk you can address this with extra mechanisms (cf. suggestions at the end). But never will it result in adding extra roles, such as one per resource, as it does not fit in any security model.

That being said, finally, here are the **roles and authorizations scheme you may come with**:

```
SCOPE / AUDIENCE
   MY_APP

ROLES
   USER
   CONTRIBUTOR
   ADMINISTRATOR

CLAIMS / ATTRIBUTES
   CATEGORIES
   ACTIONS


--> POSSIBLE USER GROUPS       
      USERS
         Roles: USER
         Claims: CATEGORIES(variable), ACTIONS('download')
      CONTRIBUTORS
         Roles: USER, CONTRIBUTOR
         Claims: CATERGORIES(variable), ACTIONS('download', 'upload', 'edit')
      ADMINISTRATORS
         Roles: USER, CONTRIBUTOR, ADMINISTRATOR
         Claims: CATEGORIES(*), ACTIONS(*)
```

Following this model, assigning the correct group to each registered user will provide high-grade security by mitigating/controlling the main risks. As claims/attributes are defined in the token(s) (managed and signed by Keycloak) then you can trust this information in your application and serve your resources accordingly and safely. There is also no risk of illegal access or discovery of resources as you are using UUIDs, only registered users having had access once to a resource will know it and registration with appropriate category access will be needed for another user to access it (to only be able to read it basically). Of course you may store in a database the list of resources to which each user has access to, raising the overall security to a very high level.

However, if the latest is not enough you may also implement rolling UUIDs or temporary links for your resources when served to users. To go farther you may also define groups and masks for your categories, resources and actions.

In fine, in this example I made use exclusively of **token claims** to define `roles` (common claim), `categories` and `actions` (custom claims). In terms of security the authentication and identity will be the first-line security followed by roles then categories, actions and stored list of resources per user (db).

---

Other alternatives are obviously possible, its just an example. Still, I hope it helps!

Comment: Note: whether or not your final resources are URL (as you are stating they are "non-URL"), this example will remain valid. Just translate the process (categorizing, grouping, UUIDs or equivalent, masks, ...) to your very use case. As soon as your application can understand roles (preferably) and process token claims, then the first security layers will be well in place. The rest will depend on your application.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem you should start from defining [client scope mappings](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_role_scope_mappings) for each of you applications (e.g. oidc clients). Main idea of this facility is that even if your user is super duper admin with all existing roles, all of his roles actually don't required for any particular application. For example client **foo** which defines following roles:

- foo_user
- foo_viewer

to perform its security logic need to know only whether currently logged user has *foo_user* or *foo_viewer*, but it doesn't care about has this user roles *bar_user* or *bar_admin* from application **bar**. So our goal is to make Keycloak return for any client access token with only valuable set of roles for this client. And **roles scope mappings** is you friend here. You can set for client **foo** scope like:

- foo.foo_user
- foo.foo_viewer
- bar.bar_admin

and now even if logged user has role "bar.bar_admin" this will not go to access_token since client foo doesn't take this role into account. After applying some scope settings you can test them at 'Clients -> $CLIENT_OIDC_ID -> Client scopes tab -> Evaluate sub tab.

As for you case with 400 roles, i'm quite confident that none of your application requires all of 400 roles, so precise scope configuration for you apllications can drammatically reduce access token size.

But if i'm mistaken and you really have an application that rely on large amount of roles you should look into you runtime settings.

For example if you run keycloak behind reverse proxy like nginx large tokens may not fit in default HTTP parameters buffer size (afaik about 2-4kb) so you have to increase it via appropriate nginx configuration option. Another example is tomcat which has about 16kb as default HTTP header buffer, so if you send request with very large access token in Authorization header Tomcat may not handle this request properly.

Comment: What we have are about 3000 resources (non-URL) that are identifiable by strings on the back end. Each user will have a list of accessible resources. So a role was created for each resource and assigned to users if they have access to that resource. This way, when the access token is passed to the back end, we can look up the roles and get a list of resources the user has access to. Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Role based access control (RBAC) is not suitable for your case. See Authorization services capabilities documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_resource_server_overview

Comment: yes, I saw that but does it really apply to my case because my resources are not HTTP resources. If I do define 3000 non-HTTP resources I need to be able to get a list of the names of resources using the REST API that are accessible by the token holding user; but I didn't see any API like that either. With roles, even if they're not passed in through the token I can use the REST API GET /{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings to get them